# Realizar instruccion en vb segun el peso que se contenga en una carpeta

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Buenas tardes estimados, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, tengo un form el cual muestra imagenes en un control PictureBox que estan en una ruta determinada de mi pc, y se van cambiando cada cierto tiempo como un SlideShow.. lo que quiero hacer con esto y no se me ocurre como.. es poner en un control Timer con una instruccion While, o Do While, que este comprobando el peso total de los archivos en la carpeta, y que cuando este cambie de tamaño, se vuelva a cargar el codigo con las imagenes nuevas que se hayan añadido...  adjunto mi codigo:

```
Private Sub Panel_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=panelinfo;User ID=sa; Password=123456;"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ubicacion FROM fotos"
        Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If lrd.Read() Then
            lblSlideRuta.Text = lrd("ubicacion")
        End If
        con.Close()

        If lblSlideRuta.Text <> "" Then

            Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(lblSlideRuta.Text)
            ImageDir = di.GetFiles("*.jpg").Concat(di.GetFiles("*.bmp")).Concat(di.GetFiles("*.png")).Concat(di.GetFiles("*.gif")).ToArray
            Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
            frm = New Form
            frm.Name = "frm"
            FullSizePic = New PictureBox
            FullSizePic.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            FullSizePic.BackColor = Color.Black
            FullSizePic.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom

            PicBoxImagenes.Controls.Add(FullSizePic)
            AddHandler frm.KeyDown, AddressOf frm_keydown
            'frm.Show()
            TimerSlide.Enabled = True
            'EnterFullScreen(frm)
            GetnextImage()
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub GetnextImage()           
        If Not ImageDir Is Nothing Then
            If ImageIndex < ImageDir.Length - 1 Then
                ImageIndex += 1
                FullSizePic.ImageLocation = ImageDir(ImageIndex).FullName
            ElseIf ImageIndex = ImageDir.Length - 1 Then
                ImageIndex = 0
                FullSizePic.ImageLocation = ImageDir(ImageIndex).FullName
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

para saber el tamaño de la carpeta:

Código:

```
Private Function BuscaDir(sDir As String)
Dim MisCarpetas As String
Dim a() As String, i As Integer
Static iCarpetas As Integer, iArchivos As Integer
' todos los archivos y carpetas, incluso los ocultos de sólo lectura y archivos de sitema
MisCarpetas = Dir(sDir, vbDirectory + vbHidden + vbReadOnly + vbSystem)
ReDim a(0)
Do While MisCarpetas <> ""
 If MisCarpetas <> "." And MisCarpetas <> ".." Then
 If (GetAttr(sDir & MisCarpetas) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
 ' es una carpeta, redimensionamos y la añadimos al array
 ReDim Preserve a(i)
 a(i) = MisCarpetas
 i = i + 1
 Else
 ' es un archivo, lo sumamos a la variable estática
 iArchivos = iArchivos + 1
 End If
 End If
 ' siguiente...
 MisCarpetas = Dir
Loop
' sumamos las carpetas
iCarpetas = iCarpetas + i
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
 ' hacemos una recursividad a la función con cada una de las carpetas guardadas en el array
 If a(i) <> "" Then
 BuscaDir sDir & a(i) & "\"
 End If
 DoEvents
Next i
' mostramos los resultados
Label1.Caption = "Carpetas: " & iCarpetas
Label2.Caption = "Archivos: " & iArchivos
```

y para llamar a la función sólo har que pasarle el directorio en cuestión:

Código:

```
BuscaDir "c:\Archivos de programa\"
```

despues vos haces que lo muestre en la unidad que quieras conviertiendo de medida.
y te coloco como saber que tamaño tiene un archivo por si lo necesitas, 
y para saber el tamaño de un archivo hay varias formas:

con FSO:

Código:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim Fso As Object
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = Fso.GetFile("C:\a.txt")
MsgBox "El Archivo " & objFile.Name & ",Tiene un Tamaño de " & objFile.Size & " bytes", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Tamaño de archivo"
Set objFile = Nothing
Set Fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

con Len:

Código:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
MsgBox Len("c:\a.txt") & " bytes"
End Sub
```

Ahora, lo que puedes hacer para implementarlo es que al cargar o abrir tu ventana ejecute la funcion para saber cuanto pesa la cartpeta, y guardarlo en una varible(PesaXBytes), despues de eso en el evento Tick de un timer puedes hacer un if, algo asi

```
    if(PesaXbytes == ejecutas la funcion de mdedir tamaño){
//sigue siendo el mismo tamañao no hace nada
}else{
//agregaria las nuevas fotos
}
```

Algo asi se me ocurre, espero te sirva.

saludos.

Comment: el "fldCarpeta" que es? un control? una variable? me arroja que no esta declarado

Comment: ya edite la respuesta, se me presento errores al leer archivos ocultos, cambie la funcion, ahora solo ocupas pasarle la ruta cuando llamas la funcion